# Missing Standard Library Components when Cross Compiling Rust for iOS Device Architectures (Arm7, Armv7) Using Cargo

Tags: ios, rust, rust-cargo

I'm using Cargo to build my Rust libraries for iOS architectures (i386-apple-ios x86_64-apple-ios armv7-apple-ios armv7s-apple-ios aarch64-apple-ios). I'm having problems building for Armv7 and Armv7s iOS device architectures. I'm getting errors regarding missing standard library components (e.g., memcpy, memset, etc.) The build works for the simulators though (i386 and i686), as well as for Arm64.

I've tried two approaches for cross compiling using Cargo:

1. Installing the Rustup toolchain targets for all the iOS architectures.
2. Building Rustc with my configuration set to the targets of all the iOS architectures (../configure --target=armv7-apple-ios,armv7s-apple-ios,i386-apple-ios,aarch64-apple-ios,x86_64-apple-ios --prefix=$HOME/rustc-ios) per https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/building-an-ios-app-in-rust-part-1/.

When I tried approach #1, I get the following errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

```
  "memset", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_memset in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_memset.o)
      ___aeabi_memclr in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_memset.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___aeabi_memset)
  "memcpy", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_memcpy in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_memcpy.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___aeabi_memcpy)
  "memcmp", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_memcmp in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_memcmp.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___aeabi_memcmp)
  "___aeabi_dsub", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_drsub in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_drsub.o)
  "___aeabi_fsub", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_frsub in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_frsub.o)
  "__aeabi_fcmplt", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_cfcmple in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_cfcmp.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___aeabi_fcmplt)
  "__aeabi_fcmpeq", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_cfcmple in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_cfcmp.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___aeabi_fcmpeq)
  "__aeabi_cfcmpeq_check_nan", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_cfcmpeq in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_cfcmp.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___aeabi_cfcmpeq_check_nan)
  "memmove", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_memmove in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_memmove.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___aeabi_memmove)
  "__aeabi_dcmpeq", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_cdcmple in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_cdcmp.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___aeabi_dcmpeq)
  "__aeabi_cdcmpeq_check_nan", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_cdcmpeq in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_cdcmp.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___aeabi_cdcmpeq_check_nan)
  "__aeabi_cfcmple", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_cfcmpeq in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_cfcmp.o)
      ___aeabi_cfrcmple in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_cfcmp.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___aeabi_cfcmple)
  "__aeabi_dcmplt", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_cdcmple in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_cdcmp.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___aeabi_dcmplt)
  "__aeabi_cdcmple", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_cdcmpeq in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_cdcmp.o)
      ___aeabi_cdrcmple in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_cdcmp.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___aeabi_cdcmple)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I tried approach #2, I get the following errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

```
  "___aeabi_fsub", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_frsub in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_frsub.c.o)
  "___aeabi_dsub", referenced from:
      ___aeabi_drsub in libtest_sst.a(aeabi_drsub.c.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My Makefile for producing the final static library looks like this:

```
ARCHS = i386-apple-ios x86_64-apple-ios armv7-apple-ios armv7s-apple-ios aarch64-apple-ios
LIB = libtest.a

all: $(LIB)

.PHONY: $(ARCHS)
$(ARCHS): %:
        cargo build --verbose --no-default-features --features=no_network --target $@

$(LIB): $(ARCHS)
        lipo -create -output $@ $(foreach arch,$(ARCHS),$(wildcard target/$(arch)/debug/$(LIB)))
```

My Cargo.toml looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["test <test@test.com>"]

build = "build.rs"

[lib]
name = "test"
crate-type = ["staticlib"]

[features]

default = ["hyper"]
no_network = []

[build-dependencies]
serde_codegen = "*"

[dependencies]
# error-chain = "*"
hyper = { version = "*", optional = true }
libc = "*"
murmur3 = "*"
quick-error = "*"
serde = "*"
serde_json = "*"
time = "*"
url = "*"
```

I'm actually not sure I'm installing the toolchain correctly though. I've posted this issue in another question:
[Unable to override Rustup toolchain for custom build of iOS Toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466493/unable-to-override-rustup-toolchain-for-custom-build-of-ios-toolchain)

Here is the build.rs code:

```
extern crate serde_codegen;

use std::env;
use std::path::Path;

fn serde_codegen_data(data_class: &str) {
  let out_dir = env::var_os("OUT_DIR").expect("OUT_DIR expected");

  let src_name = format!("src/data/{}.rs.in", data_class);
  let src = Path::new(&src_name);

  let dst_name = format!("{}.rs", data_class);
  let dst = Path::new(&out_dir).join(&dst_name);

  serde_codegen::expand(&src, &dst).expect("serde_codegen");
}

pub fn main() {
    serde_codegen_data("audience");
    serde_codegen_data("condition");
    serde_codegen_data("dimension");
    serde_codegen_data("event");
    serde_codegen_data("experiment");
    serde_codegen_data("project");
    serde_codegen_data("traffic_allocation");
    serde_codegen_data("variation");
    serde_codegen_data("group");
}
```

Furthermore, in XCode, I've also tried linking the following libraries:

library: System
framework: Foundation
library: objc
framework: Security
library: c
library: m

Per the Cargo output warning. But, I still get the same errors.

[Update 7/21/16]

Just tried Cargo Lipo from https://github.com/TimNN/cargo-lipo, but am getting the exact same errors still.