# Unable to override Rustup toolchain for custom build of iOS Toolchain

Tags: ios, rust, rustup

I am creating my own toolchain with my build of Rust. I need this to cross compile with iOS architectures. When trying to set the default toolchain or override the current directory's toolchain, I'm getting an error regarding the name of my toolchain. These are the steps I took to create this new toolchain:

1. Create Rustup Toolchain

   ```
   rustup toolchain link ios $HOME/rustc-ios
   ```
2. Override current directory toolchain

   ```
   rustup override set ios
   ```

```
$ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-apple-darwin
error: toolchain 'ios' does not support components
info: caused by: invalid toolchain name: 'ios'
```

I've tried other names that conform to the toolchain naming conventions, but to no avail:

```
$ rustup toolchain link stable-2016-07-19-x86_64-apple-ios $HOME/rustc-ios
error: invalid custom toolchain name: 'stable-2016-07-19-x86_64-apple-ios'

$ rustup toolchain link stable-x86_64-apple-ios $HOME/rustc-ios
error: invalid custom toolchain name: 'stable-x86_64-apple-ios'

$ rustup toolchain link x86_64-apple-ios $HOME/rustc-ios
```

[Update]

As for approach #2, when I do the cargo build, I still see the compiler linking the Arm libraries from the targets I installed for the rustup toolchain (i.e., that targets I installed for #1 in /Users/test-user/src/test-rust-lib/target/):

```
rustc src/lib.rs 
--crate-name test-rust-crate
--crate-type staticlib 
-g 
--cfg 
feature=\"no_network\" 
--out-dir /Users/test-user/src/test-rust-lib/target/armv7-apple-ios/debug 
--emit=dep-info,link 
--target armv7-apple-ios 
-L dependency=/Users/test-user/src/test-rust-lib/target/armv7-apple-ios/debug 
-L dependency=/Users/test-user/src/test-rust-lib/target/armv7-apple-ios/debug/deps 
--extern serde_json=/Users/test-user/src/test-rust-lib/target/armv7-apple-ios/debug/deps/libserde_json-55921106e25a0359.rlib 
--extern serde=/Users/test-user/src/test-rust-lib/target/armv7-apple-ios/debug/deps/libserde-e281201342afb4d4.rlib 
--extern time=/Users/test-user/src/test-rust-lib/target/armv7-apple-ios/debug/deps/libtime-750bfdd52feafcb7.rlib 
--extern libc=/Users/test-user/src/test-rust-lib/target/armv7-apple-ios/debug/deps/liblibc-1f3392fe1afd1313.rlib 
--extern murmur3=/Users/test-user/src/test-rust-lib/target/armv7-apple-ios/debug/deps/libmurmur3-ab9a44fb20fb9fad.rlib 
--extern quick_error=/Users/test-user/src/test-rust-lib/target/armv7-apple-ios/debug/deps/libquick_error-729eced693f2612d.rlib 
--extern url=/Users/test-user/src/test-rust-lib/target/armv7-apple-ios/debug/deps/liburl-4690728b1e11fab3.rlib
```

Shouldn't the Arm libraries be pulled from the rustc that I built?

Comment: I think this can be closed, since the `rustup show` bug has been fixed and the rest seems impossible to reproduce with the current rustup/rustc/cargo

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the behavior you are seeing in `rustup show` is a bug in rustup related to that specific command. I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/issues/599) to look into it.

What happens when you try to do the build with your custom toolchain after configuring it with `rustup link` and `rustup override`?

Comment: Hey @brson, I posted some of the output from the cargo build above. I am not fully convinced that the rustup toolchain is getting picked up because I still see the Arm libraries loaded from the libraries I installed from rustup add target. The Arm libraries should be pulled from my own build of rustc, right??

Comment: In the output snipped you pasted there are a bunch of --extern flags that cargo is passing to rustc telling it to look in a certain place for crates, but those crates are the ones that cargo built *itself*. This output doesn't say anything about the location of the crates that *come with the compiler* (namely the standard library).

Comment: Here are two ways you can check that rustc is loading the standard library from the custom toolchain: first just run `rustc --sysroot`. This will output the path to the 'sysroot', the directory containing std. Second, you can set the environment variable `RUST_LOG=rustc_metadata::creader`. rustc should spew a bunch of crate loading diagnostics. The section beginning 'resolved crates' should show the paths of every crate, including those in the sysroot.

Comment: $ rustc --sysroot
error: Argument to option 'sysroot' missing.

Comment: When I set RUST_LOG env variable, I don't see 'resolved crates'.